# Memory Problem; I can make new files and install new software but can't download

Tags: sd-card, memory

I can make new files, folders and install new software but I can't download files from the internet (Using Iceweasel(Firefox) and Midori). When installing new software at some point it says something like "man.db: not enough memory". Also when starting the Pi, "[warn] Root filesystem full...warning" comes up. I use rasbian wheezy with a 16GB SD card. I always use root user. Any ideas what the problem is?

df command output:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs          15328248 15010504         0 100% /
/dev/root       15328248 15010504         0 100% /
devtmpfs           53720        0     53720   0% /dev
tmpfs              12396      252     12144   3% /run
tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs              24780        0     24780   0% /run/shm
/dev/mmcblk0p1     57288    18888     38400  33% /boot
tmpfs              24780        8     24772   1% /tmp
```

Comment: could you please show us the output of `df` command ?

Comment: @lenik Added ----

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try this script to find the largest existing files on your file system, helps a lot to answer the question: "where all my free space went?" =)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# $Id: largefiles.py 272 2013-02-07 22:30:48Z lenik $

import os
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    path = '.'
else:
    path = sys.argv[1]

skip = len(path)

flist = []
for root,dirs,files in os.walk( path ) :
    for name in files :
        fname = os.path.join( root, name )
        try :
            fsize = os.path.getsize( fname )

            if fname.startswith( path + '/' ) : # check for '~/..'
                fname = fname[skip+1:]

            if fsize > 20000000 :
                flist.append( ( fsize, fname ) )
        except:
            pass

for (s,n) in reversed( sorted( flist )) :
    print s, n
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found out the reason I had no free space was because when I deleted stuff, it went into a bin, and wasn't actually removed from my Pi!

Answer (score 1):

One thing that that I can think of is that you have not expanded your filesystem to fit your entire SD card.  To do this:

```
$ sudo raspi-config
```

Select the "Expand File-System" option. Then select finish and reboot.

---

Also, have you tried using `wget` to download the files you want?  In my opinion, it is a better option to downloading something then using Midori or some other web-browser.  It's very simple to use as well:

```
$ wget http://url-to-some-file.tar
```

Comment: I had already expanded the file-system, and I'll try to use wget but I can't when the download is a button

Comment: You can copy the URL from the button though by right-clicking and then selecting the copy option.

Answer (score 0):

Because on ext filesystems 'root' user has extra %5 reserved space on filesystem while formatting. Although 'df' command show as %100, you looks you're using that reserve now. If that reserved space filled up you will not create file/dir on filesystem neither.

You can check folder sizes by that command:
du -h / --max-depth 1

You will get output like this:

-# du -h / --max-depth 1
7.5M    /etc
16K /lost+found
1.1G    /data
8.8M    /bin
1.5G    /lib
873M    /var

So then narrow your search and look for other folders such as /data in my example. Delete some files on your filesystem to get free space.